# XMPP Captcha on Android

Tags: android, xmpp, captcha

I would like to implement captcha when registering to XMPP server. Basically I have an activity where we need to enter username+password for the user to register to inband account registration, which automatically created the user.

But I would also like to implement captcha, which would verify the user is in fact human. I'm using openfire, and I've found this thread: http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/38786

What's described on that page works just fine, I can enable captcha via the web-page registration form. But how can I do that in android application, is it even possible.

If not, maybe I can implement my activity to communicate directly with a web-page transparently, so that user doesn't even know it's communicating with a web page.

I guess I need some guidelines how to proceed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution for this would be to use the same HttpClient instance (available in android since 1.0) ,with cookies enabled, to download the captcha image as well as submitting the registration info. You won't be able to use XMPP client libraries to do the registration though.